# creating a border that is not connected to any other border

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to create a nav bar similar to what is shown in the image here:

[image: image here]

the idea is that it is a nav bar where the border doesn't touch any of the other borders, this could be done through hr tags, but I cant solve how to make it vertical and fit in the Nav bar

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  color: #575859;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16.15%;
  height: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #F0191C;
  color: white;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="C:\Users\Cdogb\Documents\coursework\year 1\web design\coursework 2\website\index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="C:\Users\Cdogb\Documents\coursework\year 1\web design\coursework 2\website\product.html">Products</a>
  <a href="#index">Protect</a>
  <a href="#index">Stocklist's</a>
  <a href="#index">Events</a>
  <a href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CSS` create a `height` for `topnav` that is **larger** than it's `a` child.  Then give it padding to center the `a` child vertically ..  Also add a `line-height` to your a child to vertically center the text. This is rough .. But should point you in the right direction. .. IE

```css
.topnav {
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    height:45px;                                      /* ADDED  */
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;                           /* ADDED  */
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    
    color: #575859;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 16.15%;
    height: 40px;                                     /* CHANGED */
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    line-height:40px;                                 /* ADDED */
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #F0191C;
    color: white;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">  
     <a href = "C:\Users\Cdogb\Documents\coursework\year 1\web design\coursework 2\website\index.html">Home</a>         
     <a href = "C:\Users\Cdogb\Documents\coursework\year 1\web design\coursework 2\website\product.html">Products</a>   
     <a href = "#index">Protect</a> 
     <a href = "#index">Stocklist's</a>      
    </div>
```